# Keyboard Shortcut for Notepad++ to Make HTML Coding Easily

Tags: html, editor, notepad++, shortcut

I am new here.

I'm starting learning Web Designing. I wonder when I watch the tutorial video I found on http://webdesign.tutsplus.com you might have to watch it.

I give the link for more detail http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-sleek-corporate-web-design-hd-video-series-day-3/ (PART 1) about the fourth minutes.

The author said if he used some tricks to make his coding easily and faster.
He said he will generate `<div id="TopContainer"></div>` by writing `div#TopContainer` then pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Yeah, I think it will save a lot more time. But I try to do that and do same like him. And I can't like the tutorial. I used Notepad++ 5.9.5.
I want to ask and hope getting light about this cases.
What might my understanding is wrong, or I am wrong while doing it, or it may take some add-ons or plugins so I can do it.

Very appreciated all reply and help.  I know I am very new on this field, and may it seem kidding for you. But really I need some "light" here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! +1 interesting question - that would really save some time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all,

i suggest you to use Zen Coding, its nice and quickest way to create html files, it can support many editors

[Zen coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/)

For online demo  you can check it . [Demo for zen coding](http://zen-coding.ru/textarea/)

[NOtepad++ extensions for zen coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/downloads/detail?name=Zen.Coding-Notepad%20%20.v0.7.zip)

Comment: Hi Ravi. Thanks a lot for reply. After I posted this question I try to listen and watch the video, and I heard "zen coding" and Googling it. Finally, I found it and yeapp! I think it's just about how my English listening work. I am Indonesian, and sometime need more effort to know and understand the English especially if it video (not article which I can copy and paste into translator :D ) ok. Thanks agian Ravi.!!

Comment: The link is broken, use this one: http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/downloads/detail?name=Zen.Coding-Notepad%2B%2B.v0.7.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: Now succeeded by Emmet.  "Emmet (previously known as Zen Coding) is a web-developer’s toolkit..."  See http://docs.emmet.io/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the latest version of the WebEdit plugin for Notepad++:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/WebEdit/WebEdit%202.1/